# doctrine query builder throwing a [Semantical Error]

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm having problems with doctrine query builder throwing me a [Semantical Error] the query that i'm trying build is this:-

```
   $query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
       ->select('r, m')
       ->from('Ajfit\Entity\TicketReply', 'r')
       ->join('r.mailFk', 'm')
       ->where('r.ticketFk = :ticket')
       ->orderBy('m.dt', 'desc')
       ->setParameter('ticket', $ticket)
       ->getQuery();

    $paginator =  new Paginator($query);
    return $paginator->getIterator(); //////////blows up here!
```

The error that is thrown is:-

```
  [Semantical Error] line 0, col 64 near 'm WHERE r.ticketFk': Error: Class Ajfit\Entity\TicketReply has no association named mailFk
```

The entity that the error is referring to is:-

namespace Ajfit\Entity;

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\PersistentObject;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Ajfit\Entity\TicketReply
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ticket_reply")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ajfit\Repository\TicketReply")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
 class TicketReply extends \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\PersistentObject
 {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="mail_fk", type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ajfit\Entity\Mail", inversedBy="replies")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="mail_fk", referencedColumnName="pk")
     */
    protected $mailFk;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     *  @ORM\Column(name="ticket_fk", type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ajfit\Entity\Ticket", inversedBy="replies")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticket_fk", referencedColumnName="pk")
     */
    protected $ticketFk;

   /**
    * @var integer $rating
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="rating", type="integer")
    */
    protected $rating;

 }
```

As the error details that the TicketReply entity does not have a mailFk association, however it does, is there a problem with the why that i'm writing the querybuilder?

Thanks Andrew

Answer (score 2):

Your `$mailFk` has both a `Column` and a `ManyToOne` annotation. The column annotation can not be used to stored relations.
Doctrine seems to have chosen to use the `Column` annotation over the `ManyToOne`.

Remove the `@ORM\Column` annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ajfit\Entity\Mail", inversedBy="replies")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="mail_fk", referencedColumnName="pk")
 */
protected $mailFk;
```

Do the same for `$ticketFk`